# What do you think of this logo?

Tags: logo

Would love some opinions about this logo. I am having the classic problem of being 'too close' to judge objectively.  We are a company that does Balloon bouquet deliveries.  Our brand should reflect modern and classy design.[image]

Comment: Since down votes hurt the ranking of the question I'd be grateful if you just reply telling me it sucks rather than down vote.  (Now, if you think it's a bad question, by all means down vote).

Comment: Hi Shawn, the reason this question is likely getting dowvoted is that your question is overly broad, if you would limit to a specific area and provide more information you may actually get some upvotes.

Comment: One Issue I have with the logo, is the balloons are all almost the same color, this wont translate to other forms of visual representation. at some point it will just end up looking like a cloud with lines.

Comment: The reason this question is attracting downvotes and close requests is because it doesn't follow [the guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/89608). As it stands your question is too opinion based/too broad.

Comment: The black type bothers me. Why are the balloons tied to the dot? Lot's of vertical energy in that place only. Why are they brown? Does the ".com" have to be part of the logo? The type face and layout looks correct for a serious, old fashioned balloon company. Is this a serious company? Often balloons and party items are branded with a fun, clowney look, but I don't recommend that. Whats TOR/GTA?  Add some colors, add some looseness and direction to the balloons and this setup may work.

Comment: I noticed something else that bothers me, the bouquet of balloons looks too tight because the knot is straight at the string. The knot usually hangs straight down.

Comment: The very first thing I learned about good logo design was: "Will it work in Black only?" If I converted your logo to Black only (Not grayscale, just 100% black) what would happen? Will your logo still look ok? There are exceptions to this and certainly times to break the rules, but I always go back to this as a starting point for any logo I do.

Answer (score 2):

*opinion....* so take it or leave it....

---

*Completely forget* about trying to match some ambiguous words such as "modern" or "classy". **No one** has *definitive* answers as to what is necessary to convey those types of *subjective* statements. Design an easily read, well looking logo.

I suspect it's these types of general subjective words that have at least lead your typeface choice here. I find... (what is that Bodoni Poster?) not only overused, but to me it OFTEN conveys a *"we want this to look prestigious but don't really know how to convey that."*

Typefaces don't "say" anything. It's how you use a typeface that can possibly convey a message.

Same typeface, but used differently to convey different messages:

[image]

The reality is, you generally *avoid* doing some things in order to create a more "corporate", "strict", "rule-abiding" mark thus lending to an overall less "playful" impression and hopefully in turn conveying more "professionalism" or "classiness". -- all those quoted words are quoted for a reason.... there *are no rules*. What works for me may not work for you. By no means am I stating *any* of this is "gospel".

For me, the only thing I'd consider is serif, sans serif, script, or slab... Slab or sans serif tend to be more "institutional". Serif and script tend to be more "friendly". But these too are merely generalizations based upon my own design aesthetic. So if I wanted a more "friendly" mark I'd explore script and serif first... if I wanted a more "institutional" mark, I'd explore slab or sans serif first. But I wouldn't necessary exclude other faces.

There is *nothing, anywhere*, which states a script font can't be "corporate" or "professional" or a slab serif typeface can't be "playful". It's **usage** which ultimately matters.

---

High contrast font makes for lower readibility. Not necessarily an issue. However when considering things like signage for delivery vehicles it *may* be a concern. Reducing to very small size can give a general impression of both distance reading and limited time reading (as if seen at 30mph)....

[image]

So it *may* be passable. For my taste, it is far too lacking in definition at this size. Squint your eyes a bit and it's unreadable.

---

All uppercase and letter spaced - to me, boring and not visual interesting at all. People actually *read by shape*. You are providing, at best a pattern of boxes to read:

[image]

The reality is, most may see it as a single or double box:

[image]

Using upper/lowercase makes reading easier in addition creating a more interesting visual pattern:

[image]

Although I also feel your letter spacing is too great and a tad contrived. Again, I think it may have been implemented because you are *specifically* thinking "classy" rather than the natural evolution of a design.

---

As for the balloons themselves.... completely uninteresting. Essentially all the same color. Those slight tints will be *completely lost* in most instances. Look above at the reduced version I've posted... No idea what that shape may be without the word below it. There's no definition whatsoever.

In addition, the placement at the [dot], along with the extended letter spacing, causes a *huge* misbalance to the entire mark. It is *exceptionally* right heavy and will generally make everything with the logo on it feel right heavy. There's no balance with the balloon symbol where you have it.

That being posted, you should be aware I am **not** a fan of all-centered logos/designs. I am *not* suggesting that everything needs to be centered - not at all. I'm suggesting you find better balance overall.

---

<sub>Honestly, I'd explore the tail of the Y being a string connecting to one of the Os as a balloon.. but that's merely an idea I'd sketch and play with.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Quite solemn appearance. I would associate delivering balloons to something fun. Not a circus, but at least a little color and less traditional font.

Your balloons are small, have no variety and they seem to have got stucked to the dot when they were flying away. I think they should be bigger, colorful and placed in the middle.

The twines are waste of space. Without them you'll get bigger text and balloons in the same rectangular space.

Here's an example - a few grey balls and ovals, white text and black shadow. Then the same with random color fills and backgrounds:

[image]

Comment: This is a very cool take.  I'm going to give it some thought.  Thank you!